# Patch a method outside python class

Tags: python, mocking, patch, python-unittest, magicmock

I am interested in patching a method which is called by another method in one file. Example - original.py file contains -

```
def A():
   a = 10
   b = 5
   return a*b;

def B():
  c = A()
  return c* 10
```

I want to write unit test for this file , say call it test.py

```
import mock
import unittest

class TestOriginal(unitest.TestCase):
    def test_Original_method(self):
       with patch(''):
```

How can I use patch and mock modules to test original.py. I want A() to always return MagicMock() object instead of an integer.

Comment: `patch` is not a module. Did you read the `mock` documentation, what part wasn't clear?

Comment: My bad i meant the patch decorator and the mock module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply patch out the `A` global in the module under test. I'd use the `@patch` decorator syntax here:

```
import mock
import unittest
import module_under_test

class TestOriginal(unitest.TestCase):
    @patch('module_under_test.A')
    def test_Original_method(self, mocked_A):
        mocked_A.return_value = 42
        result = module_under_test.B()
        mocked_A.assert_called_with()
        self.assertEqual(result, 420)
```

This passes in the `MagicMock` mock object for `A()` as an extra argument to the test method.

Note that we explicitly named the module here. You could also use `patch.object()`, just naming the attribute on the module (which are your module globals):

```
class TestOriginal(unitest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(module_under_test, 'A')
    def test_Original_method(self, mocked_A):
        mocked_A.return_value = 42
        result = module_under_test.B()
        mocked_A.assert_called_with()
        self.assertEqual(result, 420)
```

You can still use a `with` statement too, of course:

```
class TestOriginal(unitest.TestCase):
    def test_Original_method(self):
        with patch('module_under_test.A') as mocked_A:
            mocked_A.return_value = 42
            result = module_under_test.B()
            mocked_A.assert_called_with()
            self.assertEqual(result, 420)
```